# Installation Steps of Oralce Client 11.2

Tags: oracle, client

I tried to install Oracle Client in Ubuntu latest version.Got some problem and also unable to resolve it.Please reply asap.

```
Error Msg:libpq.so.57 is empty,not checked
```

Comment: libpq.so is client library for PostreSQL database. It has nothing to do with Oracle. You really should provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

The library `libpq` is required by Perl DBI.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq5
```

Next time you can use this command t find the missing package:

```
% apt-file search libpq.so.5
libpq5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
libpq5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.7
```